# Can Google Home support multiple accounts in different languages?

Tags: google-home

I am British, my wife is French.

Can I talk to Google Home in English and use my account while she talks to it in French and uses her account?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/07/06/google-home-now-available-france-predictably-speaks-french-now/), Google Home speaks French.

> Get ready to say "bonjour" to Google Home, French speakers. Google's
>   Assistant-powered speaker will soon be available for purchase in
>   France, and as you might expect, that means Assistant can also speak
>   French now. This comes on the heels of Google Wifi launching in France
>   late last month.
>
> It only makes sense that Assistant will be able to speak French now,
>   but it's not only the French that benefit from that. Google Home
>   launched in Canada some time ago, and there are plenty of
>   French-speaking Canadians. Well, Assistant has a mode for Canadian
>   French as well.
>
> Google Home in France has most of the same features it has in the US.
>   You can search Google, play music, control smart home devices, and
>   more. Sales will go live August 3rd on the Google Store. The €149
>   price tag is certainly more than the $129 you pay in the US, but
>   that's par for Google.

[Here's a linked Google Help post](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7071994) with an interesting sentence at the end of it:

> The Google Assistant on Google Home is only available in English
>   (U.S., U.K., Canada, Australia), Canadian French, French, and German.

And according to [this help post on the Google support site](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7323910?hl=en), you can add multiple accounts on Google Home.

---

[Here's an interesting answer](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/googlehome/vvKqQc1WKu4/QxMN8iITBQAJ) (07/11/2016) on the Google Product Forums:

> I played around with languages and got mixed results.  Sometimes,
>   Google Home understood my gringo Spanish, French, or German and
>   correctly translated a word into English, but other times it wouldn't
>   and vice versa.  Perhaps success has to do with the way the question
>   is asked and is pronounced.  As I posted elsewhere, given Google's
>   prowess in artificial intelligence and related technologies, they did
>   a poor job with Google Home.  Anyway, I got the best results by
>   saying, "Translate [whatever] from Spanish, French, or German into
>   English" or vice versa.  Finding the phraseology Google Assistant
>   likes seems to be the key in many situations, which can be frustrating
>   and doesn't agree with the use-of-everyday language Google advertises.

Apparently, Google natively replies to questions of any language. Your account language does not seem to matter.